# Generate random points around a feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I have a point file that details the number of items and their size at each feature. I would like to illustrate these features by generating the right number of points at the right size around the feature point. **This needs to be done using symbology**, so probably a geometry generator based approach.
I can think of two possible approaches:
1-Generate a random offset for each of the n points, but I have no idea how to loop though a number of items generating a randomised location for each.
2-use a geometry generator to create a polygon then fill it with a point marker fill, this would be easier but not great and wouldn't give the right number of points and some might be cut in half

[image]

Comment: Please provide some example data, including max distance from your original point.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows:
Use a geometry generator to create a polygon the size of which can be adjusted to control the density of the points. Then **apply a random marker fill** which allows expression based control of the size and number of points